# Parallel partition of labeled set

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a labaled set A, i.e. each element a in A has some value v(a) assigned to it. I want to create a vector of sets (possibly stored in vectors), where every set containes all elements a of A having the same value v(a).

Example:

A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}, v(1)=1, v(2)=3, v(3)=1, v(4)=2, v(5)=3, v(6)=2. In this case I want to obtain the following collection: {{1,3},{4,6},{2,5}}.

I want to do this in parallel (shared memory, multiple processors). I've thought about this for a while, but any idea ended up with linear (sequential) processing of all the values (i.e. my complexity was O(n), where n is the size of A).

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I meant this actually

Comment: What do you know about v(a)? Are the values bounded (i.e. between 0 and 100) or can they be anything?

Comment: The elements of A are from the set {1,...,n} and for any element a in A, v(a)=b for some b in A.

Comment: And uh, you need to access this data often and as fast as you can I assume?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: In that case it makes sense to use a vector of vectors but then you don't really profit all that much from parallel construction. You might gain some performance, it would have to be tested to know for sure. Alternatively you could use a vector of linked lists, that could be constructed easily, but accessing data isn't quite as efficient there.

Comment: I form an array of pairs (v(a),a) and then sort it - as far as I am concerned, I can do these operations in parallel efficiently (I eman approx. O(1/p *n)). And then the idea is to make a parallel for for the sorted array so that we ensure that in every thread we are processing single values of v(a). But there is a small problem - we don't know at which indces in the sorted array, the values v(a) change and the parallel for is distributed equally...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186771/discussion-between-qubit-and-piotrmizerka).